# C# convert my WPF MvvM code to Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I have a store management Wpf App that use MvvM pattern , and i use Entity Framework , in my project i have models to use them in code first to create my database tables , Xaml for views and i have (ViewModels) , All my logic is in ViewModels Classes,
so I want to create an other project for the same thing (a store manger) using Asp.Net Mvc ,
i dont have problem with models because it have its own class lib , my problem is : How i rewrite my code(that in view models) to have it in my old WPF Project and my new MVC project in the same time without repeat all my logic code Twice (one for viewModels , and the other for Controllers ), so is there any pattern to separate the logic and use it for two different type of projects in my case Wpf and Mvc ?

In other words, is there any common ground between Wpf and Mvc using a pattern like Mvvm Or the only thing i can do is converting my logic to a class lib ?

Comment: There is no common ground that I would rely on, especially since the stateful/stateless paradigm would be a factor here.

Comment: It was possible to write the same viewmodel and use it for wpf and silver light by following Mvvm Pattern , so i think maybe there is some other pattern for mvc and wpf

Comment: Business logic goes into a BLL, which is separate from your view models or your controllers.  View model and controller logic is designed specifically for the platform.

Comment: Is seems the right thing to do

Comment: Did you finally convert the WPF Application to ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is : **.Net Core Class Library** , i create a *core* lib for my models and an other for my business logic , the good thing about core class lib that allow you to use it everywhere , in wpf , Asp , Xamarin and others.

Comment: Sounds reliable. Did you finally succeed. So you you have encapsuled the business logic and must waste or recreate the view and the controller wrapper class for the .Net Core App? How much extra work would you suggest putting here into it?